# How to add swift framework to Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift-framework

What I want to do is pretty simple : adding Charts framework ([here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) on github) to an Objective-C project.
And I simply don't know how to do this. The readme says : drag *charts.xcodeproj* into your project, but where exactly ? On the same level ? Inside the project or inside a specific directory (like Products, Frameworks...) ?

Then, the readme says you should import the bridging header but an other documentations I read that this header is only needed when you include Objective-C code into a Swift project and not the other way around.

Then, among different posts or tutorials, some changes in project configuration seem to be needed but I don't know exactly which ones.

This is my first ios development on an already existing project, and I'm pretty sure this is not as complicated as it seems but everything is new to me right now and I'm pretty lost.

Comment: you need to create a Bridging header first

Comment: Ok I just did (file is empty and at the root of my project) but it still won't compile. I get an error saying : "Charts-master/Source/Charts/Charts/BarLineChartViewBase.swift:75:76: Cannot use instance member '_viewPortHandler' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"